# What is the proper Lewis structure of carbon suboxide?

Tags: bond, lewis-structure

What is the proper Lewis structure for carbon suboxide, $\ce{C3O2}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to "Electronic structure of carbon suboxide":<sup>[1]</sup>

> Indeed, the results of these electron population analyses
>   are consistent with the following resonance forms contributing
>   to the ground state of $\ce{C3O2}$:
>   \begin{align}
> \mathrm{A}&: \ce{O=C=C=C=O} \\
> \mathrm{B}&: \ce{O=C=C^\ominus-C#O^\oplus} \\
> \mathrm{C}&: \ce{^{\oplus}O#C-C^\ominus=C=O}\\
> \mathrm{D}&: \ce{O=C=C^\ominus-C^\oplus=O}\\
> \mathrm{E}&: \ce{O=C^\oplus-C^\ominus=C=O}\\
> \mathrm{F}&: \ce{O=C=C=C^\oplus-O^\ominus}\\
> \mathrm{G}&: \ce{^{\ominus}O-C^\oplus=C=C=O}\\
> \mathrm{H}&: \ce{^{\oplus}O#C-C^{\ominus\ominus}-C#O^\oplus}
> \end{align}

[1] John F. Olsen and Louis Burnelle, *J. Phys. Chem.* **1969,** *73* (7), 2298–2304. DOI: [10.1021/j100727a033](https://doi.org/10.1021/j100727a033)

Comment: I noticed the structure $\ce{^{\ominus}O-C#C-C#O^\oplus}$ is missing, is there a specific reason on why it wasn't introduced?

Comment: @AndreaL. The authors' list is based upon the molecular orbital calculations they performed.  They find that pi and total bonds are less for C-C and more for C-O, and that the central C and the Os have negative change while the outer two Cs have positive change.  This list reflects these findings.  The structure you proposed would not fit well with those findings.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like you haven't been looking for that long time on the internet since the answer is in the [Wikipedia article about Carbon Suboxide](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_suboxide)

[image: Lewis's structure of the $\ce {C302}$ compound]

Comment: The bending about the central carbon occurs too easily for this to be an accurate representation of the structure.

Comment: True, but a Lewis's structure isn't supposed to described such a bending since the Lewis's structure isn't "accurate" by definition.

Comment: @Babounet what's "accurate" by definition?

Comment: As close as possible to the reality ?